# python django decode array html codes to readable text

Tags: python, django, html-encode

I receive a bunch of binary data and I want it be become a readable string again.

```
# Get data length in bits
dataLen = headerLen + (payLoadLen * 8) - bytes.pos
if dataLen > 0:
        eventData = []
    for i in range(dataLen / 8):
        eventData.append(bytes.read(8).int)
    m.setEventData(eventData)
    logging.debug("[D] Event data: %s" % eventData)
```

which results in a log like:

[D] Event data: [87, 84, 94, 87, 44, 36,
 70, 77, 83, 52, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48,
44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 13, 10, 87, 84, 94, 87, 44, 36, 70, 77, 83, 49, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 13, 10]

If you look http://www.asciitable.com/, I know it's correct. The first characters are indeed WT^W,FMS...

How can I change this code so that the logging has a more human readable string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the codes into string characters and then join the characters together:

```
myString = ''.join(map(chr, eventData))
```

If you have a hard time understanding what the code above does look at the code below - it's quite similar. Both versions use [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to convert every numerical ASCI code to one-character string and then join the strings together. The only difference is, in the former version I replaced [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with a simple for loop.

```
characters = []
for code in eventData:
    characters.append(chr(code))
myString = ''.join(characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

To decode the characters, you will want to use the [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) builtin. To join them together, you will want to use the [join function from the string library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
# Get data length in bits
dataLen = headerLen + (payLoadLen * 8) - bytes.pos
if dataLen > 0:
        eventData = []
    for i in range(dataLen / 8):
        eventData.append(bytes.read(8).int)
    m.setEventData(eventData)
    c = []
    for p in eventData:
        c.append(chr(p))
    out = "".join(c)
    logging.debug("[D] Event data pre: %s" % eventData)
    logging.debug("[D] Event data post: %s" % out)
```